# EF Core - code first migration: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, code-first

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/new-field?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) tutorial.

Added Rating property and when run 'update-database' I got this error:

[image]

Tried to revert to previous migration but that says no migrations applied as DB up to date. Dropped DB table and rerun migration but still getting this. When I added another migration after, UP and DOWN methods are empty. Anyone has any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you haven't shared any code, so based purely off what the tutorial says and the image you posted, it looks like instead of:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
```

You most likely have

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2")]
```

since it's missing a bracket in the `alter` clause (i.e, you need a bracket after the 2 inside the string).